# Manipulating default behaviour of CMake functions

Tags: cmake

I want to change the default behavior of a CMake function like "add_library". Is there any mechanism to do so or should I write another function implementing new behavior?

I want to give some new functionality to default functions to hide injected functionality from project CMake files. So that newbies cannot properly track the injected changes and make any workarounds.

Comment: usually, such a task is performed by creating a new macro with a similar name.

Comment: So, I am working on a project, for instance "foo", I can write add_foo_library or something like that, am I right?

Comment: You are free to define any function or macro and use it then.

Comment: See [function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/function.html) and [macro](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/macro.html) docs. What goal exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added little about my aim.